# Can I ask about spoken word games here?

Tags: discussion, questions

I want to find some information about spoken word games. Can I ask about them on this site? I am thinking of games that don’t require equipment, like for instance **I Spy**.

Answer (score 7):

Strictly speaking **I Spy** would be on-topic as it hits the [4 qualifications that we use to define an on-topic game](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/a/180/15514) here:

1. Be playable on or around a table
2. Have objective rules of play and win conditions (*Ed-- Debatable, but I think it can be agreed that there is a set of general rules to follow in I Spy.*)
3. Offer dynamic challenges, either through other players, randomization, or both
4. Be playable by hand, by human players implementing all of the rules

Beyond the strict definition I think I would be OK with [good questions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) being asked about I Spy, especially since there doesn't seem to be a better home for them on the SE network.

Comment: Great! I couldn’t find anywhere else on SE to ask about the games I’m interested in (not in fact I Spy, but this was the best known example...)

Comment: Agreed. Ruling out I Spy would lead to a grey area about then ruling out Code Names, which is quite obviously on topic.